# Is it possible to make "checked" - in checkbox through Handlebars template with conditional

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I am getting a json data from ajax request as like this:

```
{
    "username":"lgangula",
    "name":"Lavanya Gangula",
    "allLocales":[
        {"name":"French (Niger)"},{"name":"French (Senegal)"
        },
        {"name":"French (Switzerland)"},{"name":"English (US)"
        }, {"name":"French (Tunisia)"},{"name":"German" },
        {"name":"German (Austria)"},{"name":"German (Germany)"
        },{"name":"German (Liechtenstein)"},{"name":"German (Luxembourg)"
        },{"name":"German (Switzerland)"},{"name":"Greek"},
        {"name":"Swedish"
        }
    ],
    "userLocales":[
        {           "name":"English (US)"
        },
        {           "name":"Swedish"
        }

],
    "message":""}
```

and i need to render this to my template. here is the condition, while i render "allLocales" to template, the "userLocales" - should be "checked" state in the template.. how to make condition rendering for "allLocales" to check the value with "userLocales" and make that as "checked" checkebox.. is it possible to do using Handlebars?

the template i am using is :

```
<script id="locale-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#each this}}
                {{#showHr @index}}
                        <hr/>
                {{/showHr}}
                <label><input value="{{name}}" type="checkbox" /> {{name}} </label>

        {{/each}}
    </script>
```

But i unable to write the conditional function for this.. any one give me the correct way please.. even including the jquery methods?

Comment: conditional function means you want to add if or ternary operator or like that ?

Comment: yes, you are correct. it is like comparison with both keys of "allLocales" and "userLocales"